# Swig C++ to python: compiling a bunch of .cpp and .h files

Tags: python, c++, swig

I have a C++ library that consists of the following cpp and h files. I wish to expose the functions in cortex.cpp to Python (3.5).

```
cortex.h
cortex_socket.h
cortex_intern.h
m3x3.h
cortex_unpack.h

m3x3.cpp
cortex_unpack.cpp  
cortex.cpp 
cortex_socket.cpp
```

I create the following cortex.i file swig:

```
%module cortex
%{
#include "cortex.h"
#include "m3x3.h"
#include "cortex_intern.h"
#include "cortex_socket.h"
#include "cortex_unpack.h"
#include "stdbool.h"
%}

%include "cortex.h"
```

Next, I use the following to compile the module:

```
swig -python -Isrc cortex.i
g++ -Isrc -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.5 -c cortex.cpp cortex_wrap.c
g++ -shared -fPIC -o _cortex.so cortex.o cortex_wrap.o
```

These commands do not return an error. However, when trying to use the resulting module in python, an error pops up:

```
>>> import cortex
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "cortex.py", line 28, in <module>
    _cortex = swig_import_helper()
  File "cortex.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_cortex', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: ./_cortex.so: undefined symbol: _Z13GetHostByAddrPhPc
>>>
```

I have found several other questions/answers on this forum relating to this error. However, as am not familiar with swig anc C++ it's difficult for me to to translate these to my own situation, code and commands - in other words: even after reading these other posts, I am still lost.

I've collected the snippets of code above from various sources on the web. Hence, I would also be grateful if someone explained me what these lines of code do (which might help me finding a solution).

In any case, some help would be great.

Comment: OK, my bad. Edit: removed some trailing word.

Comment: You probably need to link your shared library against something else.

Comment: I don't know. GetHostByAddr is defined in one of the header files in my library. It's in the the cortex_socket files.

Comment: You've not actually shown us anything about the C++ library itself, but more likely that `GetHostByAddr` is *declared* in the header file, but defined elsewhere. Hence when Python loads the extension there's a reference to the function, but because you've not linked against a definition of it it's undefined.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply.

I found this in the cortex_socket.cpp file. Wouldn't this be the definition of the GetHostByAddr function?

`int GetHostByAddr(unsigned char Address[4], char *szName)
{
    hostent* pHostEnt;

    pHostEnt = gethostbyaddr((char*)Address, 4, PF_INET);

    if (pHostEnt == NULL)
    {
        LogMessage(VL_Error, "Unable to get CortexHost name information");
        return RC_NetworkError;
    }
    strcpy(szName, pHostEnt->h_name);

    return RC_Okay;
}`

Sorry for the markup - not sure how to reply with a properly formatted reply.

Comment: That looks like a definition, but you've not got that anywhere inside your SWIG module and you've not linked the module against it which is what you need to do. Probably when you build that library it compiles a .a or .so file at the end. When you compile your SWIG generated code you need to link against that.

Answer (score 0):

When wrapping C++ code, it is critical that SWIG be called with the `-c++' option.